# Writing a script to rename improper files

Tags: python-3.x, windows

so I'm trying to write a script that will search a given path for files that contain for example "Disqualification_of_counsel-.pdf.~tmp@d#260904795^9ff1be71-a06c-4a48-a985-6acd63080bfb" and change the file name to Disqualification_of_counsel.pdf without the garbage added at the end, also for files that end in docx, or doc as well. Last I'd like for it to write the output out so I can see how far the script has gotten. I'm still learning python so forgive me the script is incomplete since I'm a little lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

So far I've gotten a basic script that I need to have looked over, please forgive me for my lack of knowledge on this topic.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
def main():

    print ("Please enter where the files are located")
    user = input()
    path = Path(_file_).parent.absolute()
    filenames = os.listdir(path)

if path.exist() == user:
    print(""Running script"")
for filename in filenames:
    os.rename(filename, filename.replace("", "")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import re

user = input("Please enter where the files are located")
path = Path(user).absolute()
if path.exists():
    print("Running script")
    filenames = os.listdir(path)

    for filename in filenames:
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), 
                  os.path.join(path, re.sub(r"([^\.]+\.[^\.]+).*", r"\1", filename)))

    print("done")

else:
    print("does not exist")
```

> I'm using regex when I do `re.sub`. If If you are not familiar with regex, take a look at those links:
>   https://regexr.com/
>   https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html

Comment: That actually works perfectly except it's not updating docx or doc files. The pdf files are working flawlessly. Any suggestions? Thanks by the way.

Comment: That's weird, there is no reason for such an issue (and it works for me when I try). Are you sure the .doc files are not locked because word is open or anything like that?

Comment: I got it working, thank you for your help, I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Glad to know it! remember to mark the question as solved.